# Which way to describe uart interface modports?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I need to create uvm_environment of uart interface. The work almost done, except interface itself. I want to have two modports each contained input as rx and output as tx.

```
 DUT/UVM       if        DUT/UVM
 -------     ------      -------
|in   rx|<--|rx\ /rx|-->|rx  in |
|       |   |   x   |   |       |
|out  tx|-->|tx/ \tx|<--|tx  out|
 -------     ------      --------
```

I thought about something like this:

```
interface uart_internal_if();
    logic rx,tx;
endinterface
interface uart_if ();
    uart_internal_if if1;
    uart_internal_if if2;

    assign if1.rx = if2.tx;
    assign if2.rx = if1.tx;

    modport device1(input if1.tx, output if1.rx);
    modport device2(input if2.tx, output if2.rx);
endinterface
```

If it would work, I would be have equal modports and I would be not bothered of considirating which pin should be ouput for the DUT same for tb env. If I create inteface with names like rx1, tx1 I would have to always think which modport should go to the UVM and that's not good.
Problem is, as I understand, I can't use internal interfaces in the modports, because I have following error:

```
 near ".": syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')' or ','
```

Is it possible to describe such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SystemVerilog has a feature called *modport expressions*. This is similar to *port expressions* where the name of the port is different from the signal it is connected to.

```
interface uart_if ();
logic l1, l2;

    modport device1(input .rx(l1), output .tx(l2));
    modport device2(input .rx(l2), output .tx(l1));
endinterface
```

Then whichever modport you connect to, you can read rx, and write to tx.

```
module DUT(uart_if.device1 ut);

// ut.rx is really l1
// ut.tx is really l2

endmodule
```